# Hibernate in Spring - delete with subqueries

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to perform a delete with the use of Hibernate but it doesn't work... 
I know how to do it with the use of SQL query but I want to use HQL as it's Hibernate.
In sql my delete queries would look like that:

```
DELETE FROM timetable WHERE id in(SELECT timetable_id FROM timetable_timetable WHERE timetable < CURDATE())

DELETE FROM timetable_timetable WHERE timetable < CURDATE()
```

these two tables in database look like that:

timetable(1st one) , timetable_timetable:(2nd one):

[image: timetable]

[image: timetable_timetable]

My Timetable class: (code without getters setters and constructors)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "timetable")
public class Timetable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ElementCollection
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "timetable_id")
    private List<Date> timetable;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie")
    private Movie movie;

    @Column(name = "dubbing")
    private boolean dubbing;

    @Column(name = "subtitles")
    private boolean subtitles;

    @Column(name = "threeDimensions")
    private boolean threeDimensions;
}
```

I have no idea how to do it. I've search trough the Internet but I didn't found anything what would work. I thought that I will divide the first delete query into two subqueries like that:

```
    Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT id FROM Timetable.timetable WHERE timetable < :today");

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    q.setParameter("today",dateFormatter.format(today));
    idToDeleteList = q.list();
    String hql = "DELETE FROM timetable WHERE id in :timetable_id";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter("timetable_id", idToDeleteList);
```

but it throws exception that the parameter 1 is wrong....
I will be really grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
String hql = "DELETE FROM timetable WHERE timetable < :today";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setDate("today", today);
query.executeUpdate();
```

Or use a native sql.

Comment: Yeah, true, it's wrong. Actually I didn't check it beacuse my select query throws the exception first.

Comment: Anybody knows the answer? I still didn't manage to figure it out:(